# Android Google Gson convert object toJson is null value

Tags: android, serialization, gson

I am using google gson version 2.4
I have added file gson-2.4.jar to my Android project in Android studio under libs folder. The code build successfully.

My code is as below

```
class Test{
        private final int id;
        private final String name;
        public Test(){
            id = 1;
            name = "Hello world";
        }
    }
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
    Test test = new Test();
    gsonBuilder.setPrettyPrinting().serializeNulls();
    Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

    String json = gson.toJson(test);
    System.out.print(json);
```

The json is always null value.

My expected result as

```
{"id":1,"name":"Hello world"}
```

How can i fix it?
Thanks

Comment: you mean `json` is null ?

Comment: @Blackbelt, my expected result is {"id":1,"name":"Hello world"}

Comment: if json is null, `System.out.print(json)` will make crash your app

Comment: I run app with debug mode to watching json's value. There is a breakpoint at line System.out.print(json); :D

Comment: maybe the debugger didn't have evaluated the variable. Does it crash you run it without debugger ?

Comment: code is inside `try{ ...code here ... } catch(Exception ex) { /*hahaha debug this su*** */ }` :)

Comment: No, It does not crash!. I have use Toast to show message. Its value still is null.

Comment: where is the Toast ?

Comment: @Selvin, I put it to try{} catch statement, but there are not any exceptions

Comment: @huynhthinh if my suggestion is what answer your question, please mark it as Answered.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are implementing it in another way as it should...

```
class Test{
        private final int id;
        private final String name;
        public Test(){
            id = 1;
            name = "Hello world";
        }
    }

public String convertToJson(){
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        return  gson.toJson(this);
}
```

and this should print out what you are expecting:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Hello world"}
```